# Random Variables: $2X$ vs $X + X$

Tags: random-variables

Given some random variable $X$, how should I interpret addition: $X+X$?

Two independent potentially different results added together? Or on the other hand, one result doubled $X+X= 2X$.

Similarly, is $X-X$ equal to $0$?

---

References:

- [Is the sum of random variables X and X 2X?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1618991/is-the-sum-of-random-variables-x-and-x-2x)
- https://apcentral.collegeboard.org/courses/ap-statistics/classroom-resources/random-variables-vs-algebraic-variables
- https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/235678/why-is-x-x-2x-but-x-x-neq-2x?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1618991/is-the-sum-of-random-variables-x-and-x-2x

Comment: Hi, just saying, you can also use MathJax (math typeset) in your question heading.

Comment: Arithmetic does not go away because the quantities are measurable functions.

Comment: $X + X$ is just $2X$ and $X - X$ is just $0$ as usual. If you want to sum two independent copies of $X$ you should refer to them using different notation, e.g. $X_1 + X_2$, because they are not literally the same random variable.

Comment: Interesting there seems to be a difference of opinion floating around: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/235685/100648

Comment: @David I feel like what you should be getting out of the link you just cited is that *among mathematicians* there is no difference of opinion about $X+X$: all are in agreement that it is the same as $2X$. What AP Central thinks about notation for random variables is another matter. (But I worry that we may be approaching the $6/3(-2)$ levels of nonsense here: the point is that **the sum of a random variable with itself** is different from **the sum of two independent copies** and you always make sure to clearly communicate which you mean. Everything else is commentary.)